# Macros in elixir

Tags: elixir, metaprogramming

I am new to meta programming . I have a module like this

```elixir
defmodule transport do
  use Qber.Web, :status
  some[some_option]
end
```

In my `web.ex`. I have define this `status` like this:

```elixir
 def status do
  quote do
    use Qber.Status
  end
 end
```

This is my status module

```elixir
 defmodule Qber.Status do
   @moduledoc """

   """
   defmacro __using__(_options) do
     quote do
       code
     end
   end
   defmacro some(options) do
     quote do
       options = unquote options
       IO.inspect options
     end
   end
end
```

When i use Qber.Web,:status.its working fine but I also want to send the value from `some` to the macro in the status module right now its giving error `some` undefined in transport. How can i do this?

Comment: Can you post the exact error message and if possible an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @Dogbert This is the error warning: variable "some" does not exist and is being expanded to "some()", please use parentheses to remove the ambiguity or change the variable name
  Transport.exs:4

** (CompileError) Transport.exs:4: undefined function some/0

Comment: Shouldn't it be `some(some_options)` or are you trying to magically inject the `some` variable at some point? It is best if you state which problem you are trying to solve, since meta-programming is rarely the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do exactly without some more context.

However, `use` doesn't import functions or macros, try adding `import`:

```elixir
 defmodule Qber.Status do
   defmacro __using__(_options) do
     quote do
       import Qber.Status
       code
     end
   end

   defmacro some(options) do
     quote do
       options = unquote options
       IO.inspect options
     end
   end
end
```

Also, it's worth repeating what [José said in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416828/macros-in-elixir/48418902#comment83825261_48416828):

> It is best if you state which problem you are trying to solve, since meta-programming is rarely the answer.